# Inventor imported object has different reflective properties than blender made one

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, materials, import, glass

I've been using Inventor 2020 for some mesh design for different things and decided to test an imported object and how well I could create materials for it in Blender. [image]

For some reason however, the way the Inventor glass (Right) reacts with light is drastically different than the way a quickly made Blender glass (Left) reacts with it (Same material).

[image]

The meshes of the glasses are of course different, but similar enough in the bezels, and thickness of the mesh that I don't think I should be seeing such different results in appearance (but maybe I'm wrong).

How would I either change the imported mesh to behave the same as the smaller glass, or change my material nodes to accomplish a similar affect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I'm dumb, the Inventor glass broke on a thickness function and only the rounded lip was defined, with a correct thickness the glass reflects and refracts as expected! Blender treats a glass plane differently than a glass mesh in terms of reflective properties, hence the issue of differing appearances!

Comment: You are talking about the way it bends / refracts light, right? Yes, a thicker lens will look different than a thinner one, even with the same IOR (index of refraction) setting. Also, I'd also convert those triangles to quads (Edit Mode, select all, ALT+J) and make sure you use the same AutoSmooth settings for both. For fun, you might also try a flat material and put a solidify modifier on it to quickly change or animate the thickness. This could be helpful in making a glass too.